# Creating an association that's not in the database

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using code-first with an existing third-party database. With this database I am allowed to add tables but not change the existing tables. The tables in the database don't have any built-in relationships, but the entities **are** related:

```
<Table("OrderItems")>
Partial Public Class OrderItem

    <Key>
    Public Property OrderItemID As Integer

    Public Property ProductId As Integer?
End Class
```

I want this to map to `Product` however I can't simply do this:

```
<ForeignKey("ProductId")>
Public Property Product As Product
```

Because it will want the tables to have the foreign key constraint.

How do I create this mapping without changing the existing tables?